# How do you roll up data for use in a heatmap in R?

Tags: r, csv, data-visualization

I have data of the form

```
Site,Year,Month,Count,Action
Site A,2012,1,10,Action A
Site A,2012,2,9,Action A
Site A,2013,1,12,Action A
Site A,2013,2,3,Action A
Site B,2012,1,6,Action A
Site B,2013,1,2,Action A
Site A,2012,1,3,Action B
Site A,2013,1,2,Action B
Site B,2012,1,20,Action B
Site B,2013,1,12,Action B
...
```

Then from there, I want to apply a function `f(x,y)` to produce a table by Site, Year, Month, and Action for a given month:

```
Site,f,Action
Site A,f(10,12),Action A
Site A,f(3,2),Action B
...
```

Where the input to `f(x,y)` will  be `x` equals the count for 2012, month 1 by Site, Year, and Action, and `y` will be the count for 2013, month 1 by Site, Year, and Action.

I want to be able to produce a table/matrix like this in **R** for any given month.

This is in preparation for supplying this data to `heatmap` to try and visualize year over year changes by month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` provides the simplest syntax:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,list(f = f(Count[Year==2012], Count[Year==2013])), by=list(Site, Action, Month)]
```

Comment: `aggregate` is a good base R function, although subsetting the year within the function may be trickier?

Comment: I tried this an I get an error with the message `negative length vectors are not allowed`. Any ideas?

Comment: So clean with data.table! +1

Comment: @drsnyder Not sure - this works with the sample data you provided.